# Get reference from object to other

Tags: c#, wpf

Following is my code block:

```
class MyClass: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
     ClearPendingBill cpb;
     public ClearPendingBill CPB
     {
        get { return cpb; }
        set
        {
            cpb = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("CPB");
        }
     }
}

public partial class ClearPendingBill : UserControl, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    protected bool SetField<T>(ref T field, T value, string propertyName)
    {
        if (EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(field, value)) return false;
        field = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
        return true;
    }

    double _selected_pending_amt = 0;
    public string SelectedPendingAmount
    {
        get { return "₹ " + string.Format("{0:0,0.00}", _selected_pending_amt); }
        set
        {
            SetField(ref _selected_pending_amt, Convert.ToDouble(value), "SelectedPendingAmount");
        }
    }
}
```

In the above code object of ClearPendingBill is created inside MyClass. Is it possible somehow to refer MyClass object from ClearPendingBill object?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Unrelated: your UserControl should not implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

Comment: Curious - why would it need to do that? For what purpose?

Comment: My actual code is very large and complex. I have just placed very few things from it in this question.

Comment: Your UI class should reference a data class, not the other way around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course there is, you have to pass it on construction, or through some other method on `ClearPendingBill`.

If you wrote:

```
ClearPendingBill cpb = new ClearPendingBill(this);
```

It would give it a reference to the owning object (of course you need a constructor to handle it). Static methods on `MyClass` are always accessible (as long as they are public).

As written though, there is no way to get the owning object.

Comment: oh thanks a lot!! I should have thought about this :)

Answer (score 0):

Not without a back-reference, because the object *could* be contained by multiple (or no) objects.

I assume you're wanting to notify the containing class that a property has changed.  One way to do that is to have `MyClass` add a handler for the `PropertyChanged` event of the `ClearPendingBill` class.